# Using an iMac to extend a Wireless network

Tags: network, wifi, imac

I'm right on the edge of my WiFi range, but my iMac is hard-wired with Gigabit Ethernet. Is it possible to use my iMac's Wifi to extend the range of my wireless network to provide better connections to my mobile devices?

I know I can setup a separate network with my iMac, but it would be ideal to stay on a single network in various parts of the building.

I'm using a Late 2012 iMac.

Comment: are you talking about wifi sharing ?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to connect my iPhone, iPad, etc. wirelessly to the iMac, and then to the internet from there. Only when those devices are too far from my Wifi Router to get a good connection on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? [WiFi Sharing](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-your-mac-as-a-wi-fi-hotspot-and-more--mac-46462)

If so, you can create a network with the same SSID and password as your existing network

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.